# Dependency injection on child object

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, .net-core, asp.net-core-1.0

I'm trying to find how I can use dependency injection to inject a ConnectionString or a custom AppSetting object so far i end up in the startup using

```
services.Configure<IConnectionStrings>(Configuration.GetSection("MyConnection"));
```

example layer

- Web MVC application
- Business Logic (class library)
- Repository (class library)
- DAL (class library)
- Model (class library)

where web see only Business logic and so on, on model is available for all.

In the DAL project I have an object that takes care of connecting and running queries against my database (CDbTools object).

Now, how can I inject directly into CDbTools without going from controller down to DAL.

Thank you.

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1):

Dependency injection definitely takes a little getting used to, and you won't be creating objects quite the way you're used to. What you want to do is first is modify your CDbTools to take the injected strings.

```
public CDbTools(IConnectionStrings strings)
{
    _connectionString = strings
}
```

The next step will be to actually inject the CDbTools into the classes that need it as well. First, register it in the startup.

```
services.AddScoped<CDbTools>();
```

You'll need to follow this up the chain. Don't think of it as passing the objects from the top level down - that will mess up your separation of concerns. Each layer has the lower layer injected in. This won't just get you the injection of your string you are looking for. It will let you mock things easier, swap layers easier, and a slew of other benefits.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you should add this to your ConfigureServices method:

```
services.Configure<CustomSettings>(settings =>
{
    Configuration.GetSection("CustomSettings").Bind(settings);
});
```

Where services is your IServiceCollection object and CustomSettings is your custom configuration class that you want to inject. That custom object should map to your settings fields.

Hope this helps!

Comment: how this take care of passing it to my custom object? as i i add in the Ctor it won't compile as i need to pass it all the way from controller up to DAL

Comment: If I understand your question, you would then add the injectable object into the constructor of your controller. That's how dependency injection works.

This link might be of more help:
https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/fundamentals/configuration.html